# Unable to Show Widget on the Page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to add a employee status widget on my project, but for some reason the widget is not showing on the page. I checked the JavaScript console, but I didn't see any errors.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
    var employees = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var statusHTML = '<ul class="bulleted">';
    for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i += 1) {
      if (employees[i].inoffice === true) {
        statusHTML += '<li class="in">';
      } else {
        statusHTML += '<li class="out">';
      }
      statusHTML += employees[i].name;
      statusHTML += '</li>';
    }
    statusHTML += '</ul>';
    document.getElementById('employeeList').innerHTML = statusHTML;
  }
};
xhr.open('GET', 'data/employees.json');
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information please?

You show us the code, which in itself seems fine, but we will not know if you have an invalid document reference or some other error until you show us more.

That said, since you are saying no errors are reported, it may be a CSS definition causing the element not to appear. Why not add some html directly to the 'employeeList' element and see if it appears on the screen at all.

Comment: I did add some text in the 'employeeList' element and it showed on the page.

Comment: Try changing "innerHTML" to "append". Can you copy over some of the code to fiddle so I can mess with it however you have it?

Comment: Hey Kenneth, thank you so much for your effort. Turns out, I was missing the css file. Again, thank you so much!